# Icon for Tracking Responses to Meeting Requests in Outlook 2010 is gone

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, icons

In Outlook 2002 and 2003, small icons shaped as heads helped track meeting responses.

In Outlook 2010, I see no such "heads."

Have they totally gone away or is there a way to restore them for tracking purposes. I know I can use the Tracking button on the Meeting tab of the Ribbon, but I prefer seeing the heads in the appointment in the Calendar and using it to see who has responded.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this technet thread](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/outlook/thread/f56684b9-120e-49a7-8063-eb04c646fcd3/), it would appear that the "heads" icons are gone.

I can't seem to find any official MS notice of this however.